# Adding random numbers to pair lists for compare

Tags: c#

Wondering if i could get some help here. I have some code that creates 2 pairs of numbers. I am comparing them with the .except. The question i have is instead of assigning the numbers like shown in my code how do I add 50 random throws to the pairs for comparison.

```
    public FrmDieRoller()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public class Pair
    {
        public int FirstDie { get; set; }
        public int SecondDie { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pair2
    {
        public int ThirdDie { get; set; }
        public int FourthDie { get; set; }

    }

    public static List<Pair> ConvertToPairs(int[,] dieValues)
    {
        var query = from int item in dieValues select item;
        var p1Rolls = query.ToList();
        List<Pair> pairs = new List<Pair>(p1Rolls.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i <4  ; i += 2)
        {
            pairs.Add(new Pair() {FirstDie = p1Rolls[i], SecondDie =
            p1Rolls[i+ 1]});
        }
        return pairs;
    }

    public static List<Pair2> ConvertToPairs2(int[,] dieValues1)
    {
        var query = from int item1 in dieValues1 select item1;
        var p2Rolls = query.ToList();
        List<Pair2> pairs1 = new List<Pair2>(p2Rolls.Count);
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j += 2)
        {
            pairs1.Add(new Pair2() {ThirdDie = p2Rolls[j], FourthDie = 
            p2Rolls[j + 1]});
        }
        return pairs1;
    }

    public void btnRoll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   

        int[,] dieValue1 = {{1,2},{3,4}};
        int[,] dieValue2 = {{2,6},{5,1}};



        var p1Rolls = ConvertToPairs(dieValue1);
        var p2Rolls = ConvertToPairs(dieValue2);

        foreach (var item in p1Rolls.Except(p2Rolls))
        {

        lstRollDifference.Items.Add(string.Format("Player one has [{0},

        {1}] which Player two does not", item.FirstDie, item.SecondDie));


        }
```

Comment: Your code won't work. You can't call `Except` on objects that don't override `GetHashCode` and `Equals`.

Comment: If you try with this code - `int[,] dieValue1 = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } }; int[,] dieValue2 = { { 2, 6 }, { 5, 1 }, { 3, 4 } };` - you'll see that you still get told that `"Player one has [3, 4] which Player two does not"`.

Comment: I apologize i am still new to c# could you please explain a little more regarding the gethashcode and except

Comment: By default objects in C# are compared by reference. Meaning that two objects with the same values are not considered equal unless they are the same object. In order to have two different object with the same values be considered equal then you must override `GetHashCode` and `Equals`.

Comment: Have a look at this implementation - https://dotnetfiddle.net/8H25qw

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation That helps out a ton.

Comment: There's not really any reason to have two separate classes for your pairs. You can treat both player's rolls as pairs using the same class. Doing so also makes it easier to compare them.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would look at creating the random rolls:

```
private Random _random = new Random();

private int RollDie()
{
    return _random.Next(1, 7); // 7 is the exclusive max value - so real max is 6
}

private Pair RollPair()
{
    return new Pair()
    {
        FirstDie = this.RollDie(),
        SecondDie = this.RollDie()
    };
}

public void btnRoll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Pair> p1Rolls = Enumerable.Range(0, 50).Select(n => this.RollPair()).ToList();
    List<Pair> p2Rolls = Enumerable.Range(0, 50).Select(n => this.RollPair()).ToList();

    foreach (var item in p1Rolls.Except(p2Rolls))
    {
        lstRollDifference.Items.Add(string.Format("Player one has [{0}, {1}] which Player two does not", item.FirstDie, item.SecondDie));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Random` class to generate rolls, and it would be simplest to incorporate that code in the `Pair` class as shown:

```
class Pair : IEquatable<Pair>
{
    public int FirstDie { get; set; }
    public int SecondDie { get; set; }

    public Pair(int d1, int d2)
    {
        FirstDie = d1;
        SecondDie = d2;
    }

    public bool Equals(Pair other)
    {
        return this.FirstDie.Equals(other.FirstDie) 
            && this.SecondDie.Equals(other.SecondDie);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return FirstDie.GetHashCode() 
                ^ SecondDie.GetHashCode();
    }

    private static Random r = new Random();
    public static Pair RollNewPair()
    {
        // The minimum value is inclusive, the maximum value is exclusive
        return new Pair(r.Next(1, 7), r.Next(1, 7));
    }
}
```

(Like Enigmativity said, the `Except` method won't work properly without implementing `IEquatable<Pair>` and overriding `GetHashCode`.)

And then use it like so:

```
int numOfRolls = 20;

List<Pair> playerOneRolls = Enumerable.Range(0, numOfRolls).Select(n => Pair.RollNewPair()).ToList();
List<Pair> playerTwoRolls = Enumerable.Range(0, numOfRolls).Select(n => Pair.RollNewPair()).ToList();

foreach (var roll in playerOneRolls.Except(playerTwoRolls))
{
    // do whatever
}
```